# Why are my beta regression results biased?

Tags: beta-regression

I would like to use the **betareg** package, and started with some simulations to ensure I understand how it works.

I seem to be getting biased coefficient estimates in my simulation. I have made my simulation so that it roughly matches the type of data I plan to use (i.e., I have a continuous covariate, but data for evenly-spaced values of it).

```
# Covariate
theta <- rep(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 200)

# Set a slope of 1, with no intercept 
beta <- 1 

# Define the linear predictor
eta <- theta*beta

# Mean mu equals logistic function of the linear predictor
mu <- exp(eta)/(1 + exp(eta))

# If we set the first shape parameter to 1, then the following 
# is the relationship between mu and the second shape parameter 
b <- 1/mu - 1

# Draw responses from beta 
resp <- rbeta(length(mu), 1, b) 

# There will be some 1s, so squeeze the data using the strategy
# from the betareg documentation 
resp.squeeze <- (resp*(length(resp) - 1) + 0.5)/length(resp) 

# Run beta regression
br <- betareg(resp.squeeze ~ theta | theta)
summary(br)
```

My summary call outputs these coefficients for the conditional $\mu$ model:

```
Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
             Estimate  Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.19401    0.06850   2.832  0.00462 ** 
theta        0.77837    0.03605  21.593  < 2e-16 ***
```

So, it is estimating a nonzero intercept when it was designed to have a zero intercept, and a slope that is also incorrect.

I can recover the correct estimates if I change the example so that the linear predictor does not go too high, so that there are fewer responses epsilon away from one. Is the problem purely a function of needing to squeeze the data? I am just worried about using it with my actual data, given that the squeeze in the simulation is quite small, the model is correctly specified -- but the coefficients are still off. I have a lot of data in my data set (so the squeeze will also be small), but obviously I do not know that the data was actually generated through a process that follows a conditional beta.

Any advice would be much appreciated. I would love to avoid the 0-1 inflated models, if I can. (The **betareg** package has a ton of great functionality I would like to use.)

Thanks!

Comment: `rbeta` will **never** produce exact ones since it's support is $(0,1)$. Squeezing is unnecessary and introduces bias.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameterization you use is not the same as in `betareg` hence you cannot recover your original parameters. The `rbeta()` function has parameters `shape1` and `shape2` while `betareg()` employs `mu` and `phi`. The mapping is `mu = shape1/(shape1 + shape2)` and `phi = shape1 + shape2` and conversely `shape1 = mu * phi` and `shape2 = (1 - mu) * phi`.

The problem is that in your example you correctly set up `mu` so that it is linked to a linear predictor in `theta`. However, you do not specify `phi` but instead `shape1` directly. The consequence is that the implicit `log(phi)` is not a linear function of `theta` as fitted in `betareg()`.

To avoid this problem, set up a phi parameter using a log-link and say an intercept of 1 but a slope of zero. Additionally, I shift the regressor `theta` somewhat to avoid the `mu` values extremely close to 1.

```
theta <- rep(-2:2, 200)
mu <- exp(0 + 1 * theta) / (1 + exp(0 + 1 * theta))
phi <- exp(1 + 0 * theta)
```

And then you can simulate the response

```
set.seed(1)
y <- rbeta(length(mu), shape1 = mu * phi, shape2 = (1 - mu) * phi)
```

And then `betareg()` essentially recovers your parameters:

```
betareg(y ~ theta | theta)
## Call:
## betareg(formula = y ~ theta | theta)
## 
## Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
## (Intercept)        theta  
##    -0.01135      1.01680  
## 
## Phi coefficients (precision model with log link):
## (Intercept)        theta  
##     1.01608     -0.01465
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is either not convex or not locally quadratic, so a more robust optimizer than BFGS, like simulated annealing ("SANN") is needed.

The likelihood function I wrote below (zoib.ll) prints out the intercept and slope at each iteration, so you can see it jumping out of local minima. Using "Nelder-Mead" as the optimizer is much faster but only works if the problem is not too hard (e.g.,, rnorm(1000, 3, 1)).

```
library(extraDistr) # provides a parametrization of beta in terms of the mean
# and the precision
theta <- rnorm(10000, 5, 1)
beta <- 1
rho <- 1
eta.mu <- theta*beta
eta.phi <- theta*rho
mu <- exp(eta.mu)/(1 + exp(eta.mu))
phi <- exp(eta.phi)
util <- rprop(length(mu), size = phi, mean = mu)
data <- data.frame(util, theta)

zoib.ll <- function(par, data){
  x <- data$theta
  y <- data$util
  i.zero <- ifelse(y == 0, 1, 0)
  i.one <- ifelse(y == 1, 1, 0)
  i.gr <- ifelse(y > 0, 1, 0)
  i.btwn <- ifelse((y > 0) & (y < 1), 1, 0) 

  eta.mu <- par[1] + par[2]*x
  eta.zero <- par[3] + par[4]*x
  eta.one <- par[5] + par[6]*x
  eta.v <- par[7] + par[8]*x

  print(par[1])
  print(par[2])

  p.zero <- exp(eta.zero)/(1 + exp(eta.zero))
  p.one <- exp(eta.one)/(1 + exp(eta.one))  
  mu <- exp(eta.mu)/(1 + exp(eta.mu))
  v <- exp(eta.v)

  lik.zo <- i.zero*log(p.zero) + i.gr*log(1-p.zero) + i.one*log(p.one) + i.btwn*log(1-p.one)
  lik.b <- i.btwn*(lgamma(v) - lgamma(v*mu) - lgamma(v*(1-mu)) + (v*mu - 1)*log(y) + (v*(1-mu) - 1)*log(1-y))
  lik.b[is.nan(lik.b)] <- 0
  ll <- sum(lik.zo + lik.b)
  return(-ll)
}

inits <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
opt1 <- optim(par = inits, zoib.ll, data = data, method = "SANN")
opt1$par
```

Comment: thanks! Results agree with the **zoib** package for 0-1 inflated beta models, and runs much faster (for my context).